# Add Image and Text to Actions Sheet's Alert Button

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiactionsheet

I want to be able to add an icon and text to the AlertButton but the type is a type `Text?`

```
struct NavigationAddItem: View {
    @State var showActionView = true

    var actionSheet: ActionSheet {
        ActionSheet(title: Text("Select an action"), message: nil, buttons: [
            .default(Text("Option A"), action: {
                // TODO: Enter Option A action
            }),
            .default(Text("Option B"), action: {
                // TODO: Enter Option B action
            }),
            .cancel()
        ])
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showActionView.toggle()
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "plus")
                .font(.system(size: 24))
        }
        .actionSheet(isPresented: $showActionView, content: {
            self.actionSheet
        })
    }
}


struct NavigationItems_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationAddItem(showActionView: true)
    }
}
```

This code gives the the action sheet but I want to add a image to the left of the text.

Current: 
[image]

Wanted: 
[image]

Comment: Did you find a working solution and if so, could you share it with us?

Comment: I didn't find a working solution to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that it is currently possible to define your own View for the Button in an ActionSheet.

Looking at the code for the `ActionSheet` we see the following:

```swift
@available(iOS 13.0, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
@available(OSX, unavailable)
public struct ActionSheet {

    /// Creates an action sheet with the provided buttons.
    public init(title: Text, message: Text? = nil, buttons: [ActionSheet.Button] = [.cancel()])

    /// A button representing an operation of an action sheet presentation.
    public typealias Button = Alert.Button
}
```

This shows that the `Button` that the `ActionSheet` uses is typealiased to `Alert.Button`

If we look at the the struct for `Alert` we can see the following methods:

```swift
/// A storage type for an alert presentation.
@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
public struct Alert {

    /// Creates an alert with one button.
    public init(title: Text, message: Text? = nil, dismissButton: Alert.Button? = nil)

    /// Creates an alert with two buttons.
    ///
    /// - Note: the system determines the visual ordering of the buttons.
    public init(title: Text, message: Text? = nil, primaryButton: Alert.Button, secondaryButton: Alert.Button)

    /// A button representing an operation of an alert presentation.
    public struct Button {

        /// Creates an `Alert.Button` with the default style.
        public static func `default`(_ label: Text, action: (() -> Void)? = {}) -> Alert.Button

        /// Creates an `Alert.Button` that indicates cancellation of some
        /// operation.
        public static func cancel(_ label: Text, action: (() -> Void)? = {}) -> Alert.Button

        /// Creates an `Alert.Button` that indicates cancellation of some
        /// operation.
        ///
        /// - Note: the label of the button is automatically chosen by the
        /// system for the appropriate locale.
        public static func cancel(_ action: (() -> Void)? = {}) -> Alert.Button

        /// Creates an `Alert.Button` with a style indicating destruction of
        /// some data.
        public static func destructive(_ label: Text, action: (() -> Void)? = {}) -> Alert.Button
    }
}
```

Notice that each of the functions that create `Alert.Button`, they are: `default`, `cancel` and `destructive`, only take a label of type `Text` and an `action` of type `(() -> Void)?`. This means that you can only pass a view that conforms to `Text`.

So trying to pass a view that doesn't conform to `Text` won't work, as you have already discovered.

Comment: @JonasDeichelmann You could roll your own implementation of a modal (as currently fullscreen modals are not available in SwiftUI - there are plenty of tutorials that you can google) and build up the UI you want inside the modal. Not exactly ideal but it would be a work around.

Comment: Thank you. I hoped there would be a nicer work around for that.